# Guarantee uniqueness by changing other item's state

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, unique

I have a Page model that has a boolean property :is_root. This value should be unique if it's set to true, so by setting this to true on one item, others having this set to true should be set to false instead. It's just swapping the active item.

Is there any elegant, "rails" way to do this? At the moment I am using this one:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_root
  before_save :guarantee_uniqueness_of_is_root

  def guarantee_uniqueness_of_is_root
    if self.is_root?
      Page.where(:is_root => true).each do |p|
        p.update_attribute(:is_root, false) if p != self
      end
    end
  end

end
```

end

But this seems very ugly to me.

Thanks for your help :)

Arne

Comment: I would move the exclusion of self to the `Page.where` method, thus: `.where('is_root = true and id != ?', self.id)`, and might suggest `.update_all(:is_root => false)` instead of a loop, but I can't think of a better way than this in general terms.

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are looking for is not uniqueness exactly :), but there exist only one root page at a time, so when a page gets added as root, reset existing root pages, ensuring there exists only one root page at any time.

Otherwise, how one could imagine a boolean column to be unique :) having only two records :)

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_root
  before_save :ensure_single_root_page

  def ensure_single_root_page
    Page.update_all(:is_root => false) if self.is_root?
  end
end
```

In addition, I suggest, if you could store root page id somewhere else, say settings table, or some other table where these pages belong. Its not good to have such a boolean column, where you know that all values in is_root column being false, and only one being true.